# Error: This method is only meant to be run on single node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, enzyme

I am testing a keybinding feature in a component. The component is rather simple, event listener for the `keyup` and fires up a *redux action* which will hide the component.

I have cleaned up my code here to only relevant information. I am able to make the test pass if I just use the *store dispatch* to make the action call but that of course will defeat the purpose of this test. I am using Enzyme to simulate the `keyup` event with the appropriate event data (keycode for `esc`) but I come across the error below.

`MyComponent.js`

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from './LoginForm.scss';
import {hideComponent} from '../../actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
      // props
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.keybindingClose);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.keybindingClose);
  }
  
  keybindingClose = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      this.toggleView();
    }
  };

  toggleView = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(hideComponent());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        // render code
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  // code
}))(MyComponent);
```

`MyComponent-test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {MyComponent} from '../../common/components';
import styles from '../../common/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.scss';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
let store;
chai.use(chaiEnzyme());

describe.only('<MyComponent/>', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({});
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
  });

  it('when esc is pressed HIDE_COMPONENT action reducer is returned', () => {
    const props = {
      // required props for MyComponent
    };
    const expectedAction = {
      type: require('../../common/constants/action-types').HIDE_COMPONENT
    };
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store} key="provider">
        <LoginForm {...props}/>
      </Provider>
      );
    // the dispatch function below will make the test pass but of course it is not testing the keybinding as I wish to do so
    // store.dispatch(require('../../common/actions').hideComponent());
    wrapper.find(styles.container).simulate('keyup', {keyCode: 27});
    expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.deep.equal(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

Errors:

```
Error: This method is only meant to be run on single node. 0 found instead. 

at ReactWrapper.single (/Users/[name]/repos/[repoName]/webpack/test.config.js:5454:18 <- webpack:///~/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:1099:0)
        

at ReactWrapper.simulate (/Users/[name]/repos/[repoName]/webpack/test.config.js:4886:15 <- webpack:///~/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:531:0)


at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/[name]/repos/[repoName]/webpack/test.config.js:162808:55 <- webpack:///src/test/components/MyComponent-test.js:39:40)
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That error happens when, as it says, you run it with any number of nodes other than 1.

Similar to jQuery, your `find` call will return some number of nodes (really it's a single wrapper that knows how many nodes your `find` selector has found). And you can't call `simulate` against 0 nodes! Or multiple.

The solution then is to figure out why your selector (the `styles.container` in `wrapper.find(styles.container)`) is returning 0 nodes, and make sure it returns exactly 1, and then `simulate` will work as you expect.

```
const container = wrapper.find(styles.container)
expect(container.length).to.equal(1)
container.simulate('keyup', {keyCode: 27});
expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.deep.equal(expectedAction);
```

Enzyme's [debug](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html) method is really useful here. You could do `console.log(container.debug())`, or also `console.log(container.html())` to make sure your component is rendering as expected during the test.

Comment: Nothing display console.log(container.debug()). display blank because I append static string. @tyler-collier

Answer (score 4):

You don't find any node because the element that you try to reach is in another level. Select a specific element by the class, id.. and try this

```
wrapper.find('LoginForm')
  .dive()
  .find('.CLASS_NAME_OF_ELEMENT')
  .simulate('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one HTML elements like

```html
 <button className = "age_up" onClick = {() => dispatch(onAgeUpAction())}> 
        Age UP 
        </button> 
        <button className = "age_down" onClick = {() => dispatch(onAgeDownAction())}>
             Age Down 
       </button> 
        <button type = "button"onClick = {handleClick}> 
        Fetch Post 
        </button>
```

and are calling it by a generic query like

```html
wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
```

it will return all the three nodes for you.
**So call it by unique ID's or ClassNames.**

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys in my case I use
1-first get the container
2- get the button
3- execute the prop onClick

```
 it('should Click on edit row', () => {
  const containerButton =  wrapper.find('.editCell')
  const editButton = containerButton.find('.buttonAlignRight')  
  editButton.props().onClick() 
  expect(wrapper.find('input')).toBeVisible()
})
```